# C# if function criteria are fulfilled but not running linked code

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to finish a project, but the conditions I set in the if statement are fulfilled and not running the linked code. basically, I type null and it keeps running, even though it should set running to false, and it doesn't print the answer at the bottom. it's supposed to be a random number generator with variables linked to each number. I'm still new to C#, So I'm probably just using things wrong, as usual.
edit: added some fixes. also the line at the end, Console.WriteLine(answer) on line 99, is being considered unreachable, and it is the main way for me to know if my code works. if someone could let me know how to fix that, it would be great. also, could someone tell me some alternatives to the goto statement? edit 2: thanks for the help, It works now.

```
using System.Collections;

internal class Program
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string item1;
    string item2;
    string item3;
    string item4;
    string item5;
    string answer;

    item1 = "";
    item2 = "";
    item3 = "";
    item4 = "";
    item5 = "";
    answer = "";

    bool Running = true;
    while (Running)
    {


        Console.Write("Enter item 1: ");
        item1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter item 2: ");
        item2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter item 3, or type null: ");
        item3 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (item3 == "null" ) 
        { 
            Running = false;
            item3 = "";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter item 4, or type null: ");
        item4 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (item4 == "null") 
        {
            Running = false;
            item4 = "";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter item 5: ");
        item5 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (item5 == "null") 
        {
            Running = false;
            item5 = "";
        }

    }
reroll:
    Random random = new Random();
    switch (random.Next(1, 6))
    {
        case 1:
            {
                answer = item1;
                break;
            }
            
        case 2:
            {
                answer = item2;
                break ;
            }
            
        case 3:
            {
                if (item3 == "") 
                {
                    goto reroll;
                }
            answer = item3;
            break;
            }
            
        case 4:
            {
                if (item4 == "") 
                {
                    goto reroll;
                }
                answer = item4;
                break;
            }
            
        case 5:
            {
                if (item5 == "") 
                {
                    goto reroll;
                }
                answer = item5;
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(answer);
            
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "I type null and it keeps running, even though it should set running to false" - well it *does* set Running to false, but that doesn't stop that iteration of the loop - so if you enter "null" for item3, it's still going to ask for item4 or item5. Unfortunately you haven't given us much detail about what you type when, or what you're seeing, which makes it hard to help. I would strongly encourage you to avoid `goto` statements though.

Comment: You end the `if` statements with a `;`; which ends the statement and the next lines are seen as a new code block. The compiler should see it as "potential mistaken empty statement".

Comment: Actually, it's going to set `Running` to false regardless, because on *every one* of your `if` statements, you've got an empty body with just a `;`.

You should be able to see this in your IDE, because it should show you 9 warnings. Please fix those warnings...

Comment: Congratulations on proving the joke that a Fortran programmer can write Fortran programs in _any_ language. I am a Fortran programmer myself and I recognized the above code as 100% Fortran in C# disqguise.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(answer);` is inside of the `switch` block and part of `case 5:`, but the preceding code inside the brackets always `break`s, hence the call is unreachable.  I assume you want to print `answer` regardless of what was rolled, so move `Console.WriteLine(...)` down a couple lines to after the next `}`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your code is concerned I have several issues to bring up

1. When you feel the need to define variables like `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, etc then it is time to consider arrays and collections. You are learning bad habits otherwise. A fixed size array `string[] items` would suffice here, although a better solution would be to use a variable size `List<string> items`.
2. Try to divide up your code into functional parts, and use functions in order to minimize any possible side effects. This way you control the flow of information better.
3. If it all possible avoid `goto`, unless you absolutely need to. It makes code much harder to trace out and bugs are harder to catch. Alternatively use either a fixed count iteration like a `for()` loop, or a general `while()` statement and use the keyword `break` to exit the loop (or `continue` to move to the next iteration).

A lot of other smaller issues are a matter of experience with programming.

The way I read the code you are trying to do something like this

```text
Enter Item 1
aaa
Enter Item 2
bbb
Enter Item 3
ccc
Enter Item 4 or press [ENTER] or type null to end.
ddd
Enter Item 5 or press [ENTER] or type null to end.
null

User List:
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

Randomly Selected Item: ddd
```

Here is one way of getting there using the principles laid out above. The code below is intended for learning purposes, with the hope that you are going to be able to follow along and understand what does what.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get user inputs
        string[] items = AskItemsFromUser(minItems:3, maxItems:5);

        // Show what was entered as a list
        Console.WriteLine("User List:");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        // Show random item from list
        string item = PickRandom(items);
        Console.WriteLine($"Randomly Selected Item: {item}");

    }

    public static string[] AskItemsFromUser(int minItems, int maxItems)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();
        while (items.Count < maxItems)
        {
            // Change the prompt depending on the number of items entered.
            if (items.Count >= minItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Enter Item {items.Count + 1} or press [ENTER] or type null to end.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Enter Item {items.Count + 1}");
            }
            // get user input
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            // if input=="null" or an empty string
            if (input.Equals(string.Empty) || input.Equals("null"))
            {
                // and min # of items already reached
                if (items.Count >= minItems)
                {
                    // the exit loop
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // add user input to list
                items.Add(input);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        return items.ToArray();
    }

    public static string PickRandom(params string[] items)
    {
        // Use a random number generator to pick an item
        // index = 0..count-1
        int index = rng.Next(0, items.Length);
        return items[index];
    }
}
```